# Edit Joomla Contact Page Header

Tags: joomla, header, contacts

I would like to edit the h1 tag on the contact page. We only have a single contact number on the contact page and would like to change the h1 tag phones to phone.

Had a dig around in the joomla file structure but I am fresh to php so its not that clear to me!

How would i go about making this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename once word trough override system. Go to "Extensions->Language manager" then on the right side overrides, click on "new" and use search. I don't understand your issue with h1, you can enable in menu item settings page heading and insert your text for h1 tag.